Understanding a proof of the completeness Theorem for Propositional Resolution.
I'm having trouble understanding the proof of 1.3.4., the Completeness Theorem for Propositional Resolution in this book.
The main portion of the proof goes like this:

Given a (finite) set of clauses $\Gamma$ and a fixed atom $p$ in $\Gamma$ we define $\Gamma'$ s.t.

For all clauses $C$ and $D$ in $\Gamma$ such that $p \in C$ and $\overline{p} \in D$ , the resolvent of $C$ and $D$ w.r.t. $p$ is in $\Gamma′$ , and
Every clause $C$ in $\Gamma$ which contains neither $p$ nor $\overline{p}$ is in $\Gamma′$ .

Assuming WLOG that no clause in $\Gamma$ contains both $p$ and $\overline{p}$ it follows, that $\Gamma$ is satisfiable iff $\Gamma'$ is satisfiable.

I'm having a hard time understanding why $\Gamma$ is satisfiable if $\Gamma'$ is satisfiable.
My thought process has been like this:
If $\Gamma'$ is satisfiable then there must be an assignment $\tau$ s.t. all clauses in $\Gamma'$ are true under $\tau$.
The obvious approach would be to show that $\tau$ also satisfies $\Gamma$.
But if $S \in \Gamma'$ is the resolvent of $C, D \in \Gamma$ w.r.t $p$, then I don't see why $\tau$ must necessarily satisfy $C$ and $D$.
If only the literal $L \in S$ is true under $\tau$, then $L$ might only be contained in one of $C$ and $D$, so $\tau$ might only satisfy one of $C$ and $D$.
We could fix this by flipping the assignment for $p$ in $\tau$ since $C, D$ contain $p, \overline{p}$ respectively, but if we do the same for another clause we might end up with contradictory assignments for $p$.

@MauroALLEGRANZA Yes, that's essentially why $\Gamma$ satisfiable implies $\Gamma'$ satisfiable.
But $\Gamma'$ contains resolvents not the premises, so I don't think that can be used to show $\Gamma'$ satisfiable implies $\Gamma$ satisfiable.

Same argument in this post.

Thanks for the reference!

The thing that confused me is that we can't necessarily do this multiple times.
For example if you derive $q \in \Gamma'$ from $p \lor q, \neg p \in \Gamma$ and $r \in \Gamma'$ from $p, r \lor \neg p \in \Gamma$.
(Though this might be a bad example, $\Gamma'$ isn't going to be satisfiable bc. the empty clause can be derived from $p, \neg p$.)

The thing is that I don't know how to show that a similar case can't occur when $\Gamma'$ is satisfiable.
I.e. you have to choose $v(p) = T$ to satisfy the premises of one element in $\Gamma'$, but then have to choose $v(p) = F$ to satisfy another.

The key is that $\Gamma'$ must contain ALL the resolvants from each clause with $p$ and each clause with $\bar p$, not just some set of pairs.
For example, suppose after converting to conjunctive normal form and splitting them into just disjunctions, we have
$$\Gamma = \{p \lor C_1, p \lor C_2, \ldots, \bar p \lor D_1, \bar p \lor D_2, \ldots, E_1, E_2, \ldots\}$$
where every clause $C_i$, $D_i$, or $E_i$ contains neither $p$ nor $\bar p$. Then for every $i$ and $j$ (in the appropriate domain), $C_i \lor D_j \in \Gamma'$.
Given an assignment $\tau$ which satisfies $\Gamma'$, if $\tau$ satisfies every $C_i$, then we can satisfy $\Gamma$ by adding $\bar p$ to $\tau$, since $\tau \models C_i \implies \tau \models p \lor C_i$, $\tau \models \bar p \implies \tau \models \bar p \lor D_j$, and $\tau \models E_k$.
Otherwise, there is at least one $C_f$ which $\tau$ does not satisfy. But since $\tau \models C_f \lor D_j$ for every $D_j$, we must have $\tau \models \{D_1, D_2, \ldots \}$. We can satisfy $\Gamma$ by adding $p$ to $\tau$, since $\tau \models p \implies \tau \models p \lor C_i$, $\tau \models D_j \implies \tau \models \bar p \lor D_j$, and $\tau \models E_k$.
In either case, if $\tau \models \Gamma'$ then $\Gamma$ is satisfiable also, completing your sketch of the proof in one direction.

Oooh, thanks a lot for the clarification!

Resolution rule is an inference rule and it preserves satisfiability: in a nutshell, if $p ∨ q$  and $r ∨ ¬q$ are satisfiable, also $p ∨ r$ is.
Due to the presence of two complementary literals, one of them (e.g. $q$) must be True, and thus the clause where it occurs is satisfied, and the other is False; but then the other literal (e.g. $r$) must be True because we assume that the corresponding clause is satisfiable.
This means that the resulting clause: $p ∨ r$, is satisfiable.
The same for the "bottom-up" direction: due to the fact that $q$ and $¬q$ do not occur in the two clauses to be resolved: $p ∨ q$ and $r ∨ ¬q$, if $p ∨ r$ is satisfied by e.g. $v(p)=T$, there is nothing that prevent us to choose $v(q)=F$.
For more details, see Mordechai Ben-Ari, Mathematical Logic for Computer Science (Springer, 3rd ed. 2012), page 81: Theorem 4.17 The resolvent C is satisfiable if and only if the parent clauses C1 and C2 are both satisfiable.
